# Android TextView Background Image With Color

Tags: android, textview

I have a simple table layout, in the one of the row, I have time for sun rise in a text view and I am trying to have sun with purple colour for the row as background. How can I achieve this? I tried creating an image 1000px x 500px with sun and purple background, However, it does not look good on different screen sizes. What is the solution for this?

Here is an image of what I am trying to achieve [image]

Answer (score 0):

> I have a simple table layout, in the one of the row, I have time for sun rise in a text view and I am trying to have sun with purple colour for the row as background. How can I achieve this?

Save your image in drawable folder , and in your TextView add this line :

```
android:background = "@drawable/your_imagename_from_drawable_folder"
```

> I tried creating an image 1000px x 500px with sun and purple background, However, it does not look good on different screen sizes. What is the solution for this?

( This is not accurate answer but it will help you ) this online tool will help you creating images , http://labs.rampinteractive.co.uk/android_dp_px_calculator/
for this , first you have to find your emulator_dp and screen size and you can find it from emulator details section and after it you can create some good images for different screen_sizes than your previous attempts .

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with `setImageDrawable` method ?

Save your image in drawable folder
eg:`holder.row.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.yourImage));`